# Red Hat Decision Manager 7.3 OptaCloud solver example not working

Tags: optaplanner, redhat-brms

I am using Red Hat Decision Manager 7.3 and and trying to get the OptaCloud sample working, specifically when submitting the problem to the solver, which throws the following error:

```
14:51:46,266 ERROR [org.kie.server.services.optaplanner.SolverServiceBase] (pool-10-thread-4) Exception executing solver 'optacloud' from container 'optacloud_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'. Thread will terminate.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoft.HardSoftScore field optacloud.optacloud.CloudSolution.score to java.util.LinkedHashMap
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.ReflectionFieldMemberAccessor.executeGetter(ReflectionFieldMemberAccessor.java:59)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.getScore(SolutionDescriptor.java:1134)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.cloneSolution(AbstractScoreDirector.java:213)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.setWorkingSolutionFromBestSolution(DefaultSolverScope.java:218)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.solvingStarted(AbstractSolver.java:75)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solvingStarted(DefaultSolver.java:210)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:190)
    at org.kie.server.services.optaplanner.SolverServiceBase.lambda$solvePlanningProblem$3(SolverServiceBase.java:493)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This occurs when I pass in the following JSON request body to the `/server/containers/{containerId}/solvers/{solverId}/state/solving` endpoint:

```json
{
  "planning-problem": {
    "computerList": [
      {
        "cpuPower": "10",
        "memory": "4",
        "networkBandwidth": "100",
        "cost": "1000"
      },
      {
        "cpuPower": "20",
        "memory": "8",
        "networkBandwidth": "100",
        "cost": "3000"
      }
    ],
    "processList": {
      "opta.optacloud.Process": {
        "requiredCpuPower": "1",
        "requiredMemory": "7",
        "requiredNetworkBandwidth": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried different variations on the request and get the same error being logged, but I always get a HTTP 200 back from the REST call.

Any ideas as to what the issue might be (either me or a possible bug), or does anyone have a JSON request that does work. As seems to be the theme with RHDM, the documentation is less than clear.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Thank you to yurlocs answer below, this now works. I now get back the following response when I call the `/server/containers/{containerId}/solvers/{solverId}/bestsolution` endpoint after submitting the request:

```json
{
  "container-id": "optacloud_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "solver-id": "optacloud",
  "solver-config-file": "optacloud/optacloud/cloudSolverConfig.solver.xml",
  "status": "SOLVING",
  "score": {
    "value": "0hard/-3000soft",
    "scoreClass": "org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoft.HardSoftScore"
  },
  "best-solution": {
    "optacloud.optacloud.CloudSolution": {
      "computerList": [
        {
          "cpuPower": 10,
          "memory": 4,
          "networkBandwidth": 100,
          "cost": 1000
        },
        {
          "cpuPower": 20,
          "memory": 8,
          "networkBandwidth": 100,
          "cost": 3000
        }
      ],
      "processList": [
        {
          "requiredCpuPower": 1,
          "requiredMemory": 7,
          "requiredNetworkBandwidth": 1,
          "computer": {
            "cpuPower": 20,
            "memory": 8,
            "networkBandwidth": 100,
            "cost": 3000
          }
        }
      ],
      "score": "0hard/-3000soft"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct body looks like this:

```json
{
  "optacloud.optacloud.CloudSolution": {
    "computerList": [
      {
        "cpuPower": "10",
        "memory": "4",
        "networkBandwidth": "100",
        "cost": "1000"
      },
      {
        "cpuPower": "20",
        "memory": "8",
        "networkBandwidth": "100",
        "cost": "3000"
      }
    ],
    "processList": [
      {
        "requiredCpuPower": "1",
        "requiredMemory": "7",
        "requiredNetworkBandwidth": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You need to use solution's FQCN (fully qualified class name) instead of `problem-instance` as the property name when using JSON format.

Comment: Forgot to add, I had to make a slight change to the package name space for the `Process` to `optacloud.optacloud` to get the request to work with the sample project.

Comment: @JustinPhillips Good catch. I've changed `procesList` from a JSON object to an actual array. This way there's no point in using the FQCN (and no risk of making a typo in it). It's strange that in the object for, when I make a typo in the processes FQCN, it's *silently* ignored and interpreted as an empty `processList`.